# Access Browser cookie store from native Windows/Mac application

Tags: windows, macos, internet-explorer, google-chrome, firefox

Is there a way to access the cookie store of popular browser (Chrome/FF/IE) programmatically from within a Windows or Mac client application?

Or

Any information/documentation on how/where browsers store cookies on disk?

Answer (score 1):

Every browser stores its cookies differently.

Internet Explorer uses WinINET to store its cookies; there's a full API for accessing the cookies, but it got more complicated in IE8 on Vista+ due to the introduction of Protected Mode, although APIs were introduced to allow desktop apps to interact with Protected Mode cookies.

IE10+ introduced *Enhanced* Protected Mode, which makes things even *more* complicated because there's no API to interact with cookies in EPM.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2009/08/20/wininet-ie-cookie-internals-faq.aspx

> Q11: How can applications or native code add-ons retrieve cookies?
>
> A: Use the InternetGetCookieEx function.
>
> Note, by default, the cookies returned from this function will not
>   include any HTTPOnly cookies. To retrieve HTTPOnly cookies, you must
>   pass the INTERNET_COOKIE_HTTPONLY flag, available in IE8+. If you
>   decide to pass this flag, you must ensure that your code will not
>   expose the returned value to any script-controllable context. (Note:
>   It appears that support for the INTERNET_COOKIE_HTTPONLY flag was
>   added to IE7 in a cumulative update (KB960818)).
>
> Note: On Windows Vista and above, Internet Explorer runs Internet
>   content in Protected Mode, a sandbox with an isolated cookie store. In
>   order to get a cookie from the Protected Mode sandbox from an external
>   application running at Medium integrity (aka outside of Internet
>   Explorer), you must use the IEGetProtectedModeCookie function. This
>   API was added in IE8, and unfortunately, there is no straightforward
>   alternative for IE7. This API has a number of limits, in particular,
>   it cannot be called by processes running at High Integrity (Admin).